# When i click on an element add another ID or class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class, click

I have this part of code:

```
$("ul.rightside").prepend('<div id="nav_background">Colors</div>');
    $(".minwidth_IE").prepend('<div id="toggle_background" style="display: none;"><div id="custom_background"><span id="bg0"></span><span id="bg1"></span><span id="bg2"></span><span id="bg3"></span><span id="bg4"></span><span id="bg5"></span><span id="bg7"></span><span id="bg8"></span></div></div>');
    $("#custom_background span").click(function () {
        $("#account ,.minwidth_IE ,.main .main-head ,#fa_toolbar").removeClass("bg1 bg2 bg3 bg4 bg5 bg7 bg8 bg_custom").addClass($(this).attr("id"));
        my_setcookie("custom_background", $(this).attr("id"), true)
    });
```

But i want when i click on other element.. like.. #tbar, i want another class, not .bg1 2 etc. Something like bg12.. or.. i don't know!
Well: When i click on #bg3 my element will have the class .bg3! I want a function like that.. when i click on #bg3 my element will have .bg31, when i click on #bg4 my element will have .bg4..! This is for a theme changer..

Comment: What? Could you explain what you're trying to accomplish, because "I don't know"

Comment: How can we understand your question when you don't even know what you want?

Comment: You'll find that folks can be a lot more helpful if you ask your question clearly and concisely, with good examples. Consider making a jsfiddle to demonstrate your issue, and clearly state what you're asking for.

Comment: Do a bit of research and you'll realize that attr("id") on any element returns a string that can be concatenated with another string like +"1" and you can achieve the same in minimum efforts. So I'd not want to post this question here

Comment: "This is my forum: daily-support.org . I have some elements and i want for them another background, different for the background of ".bg1", but when i click on #bg1 i want the theme change. So, when i click on #bg1 i want the #account to have class .bg1, and other elements, for example #header to have another class, like bg12 (for the same click event - #bg1). To see, click on Colors, in the upper navbar on my forum. I want to change the principal navbar's background(forum, faq, search..) too but not same with bg1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

As your content is added dynamically so it is not accessible directly ,So you have to use `Event delegation`.

```
$(".minwidth_IE").on("click","#custom_background span",function () {
        $("#account ,.minwidth_IE ,.main .main-head ,#fa_toolbar").removeClass("bg1 bg2 bg3 bg4 bg5 bg7 bg8 bg_custom").addClass(this.id);
        my_setcookie("custom_background", this.id, true)
    });
```

Comment: Well, and the class of #account will be.. ? (For example if i click on bg1).. I want this for many elements. For example, when i click on bg1 the class of #account will be .bg1 and another class will be .. i don't know.. bg12!

Comment: @user2816226 `bg1`. Test this code and revert back if you face any problem.

Comment: Ohh.. you don't understand.. or i don't understand. This is my forum: http://www.daily-support.org/ . I have some elements and i want for them another background, different for the background of ".bg1", but when i click on #bg1 i want the theme change. So, when i click on #bg1 i want the #account to have class .bg1, and other elements, for example #header to have another class, like bg12 (for the same click event - #bg1). To see, click on Colors, in the upper navbar on my forum. I want to change the principal navbar's background(forum, faq, search..) too but not same with bg1